# Can we say that: $ cl\big(\text{co}\cup_{k\geq n}{\frac{1}{k}A}\big) $ is weak compact?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, convex-hulls, weak-topology

Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be a separable Banach space and $A$ be a nonempty weak compact convex subsets of $X$.

Let $n\geq 1$. Can we say that: $$
cl\big(\text{co}\cup_{k\geq n}{\frac{1}{k}A}\big)
$$
is weak compact ?
with: $\text{co}(C)=\left\{\sum _{i=1}^{n}\lambda _{i}x_{i}:n\in \mathbb {N} ,\,x_{i}\in C,\,\sum _{i=1}^{n}\lambda _{i}= 1\right\}.$

Comment: What is your closure with respect to? The weak topology?

Comment: No, with the strong topology

Comment: No!  I would never say that.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I think that is true, see my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3641637/can-we-say-that-cl-big-textco-cup-k-geq-n-frac1ka-big-is-weak-c/3657033#3657033).

Comment: @AlexRavsky.   It makes no difference it it is true or not.  We cannot say that because I am not saying that.  Were the question asking about the validity, of that statement it would have directly asked if it is true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can say that. That is even true. Indeed, let $w$ the the weak topology on $X$. Put $A’=\text{co}\cup_{k\geq n}{\frac{1}{k}A}$. Then $0\in\operatorname{cl} A’$ and $A’\cup \{0\}=\operatorname{co} \left(\frac 1n A\cup\{0\}\right)$. The latter set is an image of a compact set $[0,1]\times \left(\frac 1n A\cup\{0\}\right) \subset\Bbb R\times (X,w)$ by a continuous map $(\lambda,x)\mapsto \lambda x$ for each $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ and $x\in X$. Thus $\operatorname{cl} A’= A’\cup \{0\}$ is weakly compact.